# OAuth authentication for REST service communicating with mobile app

Tags: python, security, rest, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am writing a REST service in python and all the frameworks like flask, flask-restful, etc. and I am wondering how to secure this service. Basically it provides the information from the database about the users, their friends, some events (let's just say it is a social network) and all these pieces of information are processed on the side of the mobile device with Android or iOS (in future we will support browsers as well).

The problem is how to authenticate and authorize the user. I was thinking about using the sessions but [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hdSrT4yjS1g) great video on REST convinced not to do so. Therefore past two days I am studying how does OAuth 2.0 work and I've found that you can use [Resource Owner Password Credentials](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-15#section-4.3) scheme for authentication. Also there is this great [flask-oauthlib library](https://flask-oauthlib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for Python which can handle this.

But here comes the confusion. If I am right I should implement two-legged OAuth (not to mention all the stuff around JWT which messes me even more). But I don't understand why according to [this tutorial](http://lepture.com/en/2013/create-oauth-server) there is database table for the client (I suppose that my client is mobile app).

Could someone shed some light on this topic for me and If I am going the right direction. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, as a service provider, you will most likely want to check that any applications/clients requesting access to user data are known to you.

As such, clients will normally be pre-registered with the service provider have a set of credentials that are used to identify them.

This is especially critical in the case of the Resource Owner Password Credentials flow where applications should be highly trusted as they will have access to a user's username and password.

Hence the need for a table for the client to hold these credentials.

Hopefully that helps to point you in the right direction.